# Commercial beers made using a (triple) decoction mash?

Tags: german-beers

Are there any reasonably common beers that are made using a triple (or other) decoction mash? I'm interested in trying some but have had some trouble finding examples.

I would imagine there have to be at least a couple of breweries in Germany that still do decoction mashing, but are there any beers that make their way to the US?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source Material Referenced below. Depending on where you are located some of these I think would be available. In Milwaukee I've seen Pilsner Urquell, De Konick, Palm, and Rodenbach.

According to Gordon Strong, Pilsner Urquell uses triple decoction. This is actually a Czech style.

Another article from real beer states the following beers.

- De Koninck
- Palm
- Rodenbach
- Pilsner Urquell

[Czech Pale Lager: Style Profile](https://byo.com/stories/issue/item/3244-czech-pale-lager-style-profile)

[Decoction mashing](http://realbeer.com/spencer/FAQ/decoction.html)